# Override block function

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

I want to filter wishlist product collection with a unique id.
I have tried to override a method `_createWishlistItemCollection` located at the path `/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/AbstractBlock.php` using preference method.

This is my `di.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Send" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Send"/>

    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email\Items"/>

</config>
```

This is my block file

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email;

    class Items extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items
    {
        protected function _createWishlistItemCollection() {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testmulti.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('Your text message');
            $collection = $this->_getWishlist()->getItemCollection();
            if($this->getMid()){
               $id = $this->getMid();
               if($this->getMid() == 'default')
                    $id = 0;
              $collection ->addFieldToFilter('multiwishlist_id', $id);
            }
            return $collection;

        }

    }
```

It is not entering into the overrided file. Plese help me with a solution.

Comment: did you deployed the content using `setup:static-content:deploy` command, and before deploying delete the contents in `var/generation` files

Comment: Yes, I have deployed the content.

Answer (score 0):

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email\Items"
</config>
```

**Block.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Wishlist block customer items
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email;

class Items extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items
{
       public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
         array $data = []
       ) {
            ...
             parent::__construct($context, $data);
             echo"<pre/>"; print_r("test");exit;
         } 
}
```

Try This code for testing
After apply code remove `var/` and `public/static` and apply `setup:static-content:deploy`.

Comment: I have added the following in construct .

Comment: I have added the following in construct .
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
       // $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
       //  echo "<pre/>"; print_r("test");exit;
    }
But getting error as  Incompatible argument type:Required type \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context . Actual type:array; File : /app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Share/Email/Items.php

Comment: that means your class file is being called

Comment: use same constructor as parent used, and remove extra injections

Comment: I have used the same constructor as parent used.The block function located in /magento/module-wishlist/Block/Share/Email/Items.php has no construct method.So I have used the construct function located at /vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/AbstractBlock.php that extends the Items.php 
But still getting the error as Incompatible argument type:Required type .

Comment: have you tried by removing constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50520/discussion-between-v-p-and-ronak-chauhan).

Comment: ok lets continue

Comment: Please help me with a solution

Comment: Still not got solution?

Comment: no...it is not working

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have used a method _createWishlistItemCollection located in \Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email\Items.php and inside i have used the code to print a static content to a log file. But it is not getting dispalyed .Hence I understood  that it is not entering into function.

Comment: use same constructor which parent use and pass all parameter which parent use in parent::()

Comment: The block file is getting overrided using preference method.Can you please help/suggest me to use a custom wishlist collection on sharing a wishlist.